# Registering an Ecore model in a standalone Java application

Tags: java, resources, factory, emf, ecore

An Ecore model can be used outside the plugin-environment by manually registering the file extension and the ResourceFactory with the following command, in this case for XML:

```
Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("xml", new XMLResourceFactoryImpl());
```

My Ecore model only contains a Factory (extends `EFactory`). Where can I get the necessary ResourceFactory?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include in your classpath EMF *.jar files.

Here you can find more information: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EMF/FAQ#I_want_to_use_EMF.2C_SDO.2C_or_XSD_in_my_standalone_project.2C_or_include_only_a_working_subset_of_the_code._What_libraries_.28jar_files.29_do_I_need_in_my_CLASSPATH.3F